# Prevent vba generated PowerPoint table from auto-sizing rows

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a large macro that generates and populates a table in powerpoint based on excel values.  I manually resize the rows based on specific parameters, but I've run into the very annoying issue that I cannot seem to prevent the rows from auto-resizing if the text would overflow from that particular cell.  I've tried using the `textframe` and `textframe2` "autosize" property but this gives an error on the first call saying that the specified value is out of range.  The error number is -2147024809 (80070057), although I doubt that will be of any use.  Is there a way to prevent this autosizing beyond writing code to manually shorten the text when it will overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RGA,
the answer to your question is yes; you can do this.  This topic is discussed in the following thread: [Understanding format of tables in PowerPoint (VBA 2010) (resize text to cell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831632/understanding-format-of-tables-in-powerpoint-vba-2010-resize-text-to-cell)

However, I don't know if this technique still 'works' for ppt 2016.  I had such code implemented, and then I 'upgraded' to office 2016; now it doesn't work.

With that being said, this *was* my code (resized the text until it 'fit'):

```
...
Do Until (table.rows(1).height + table.rows(2).height < TABLE_HEIGHT) or (table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.size = 1)
    If table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.size = 1 Then
        table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.size = 27
        table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.size = table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.size - 1
        table.Cell(2, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.size = table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.size
    Else
        table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.size = table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.size - 1
    End If
Loop
```

In order to restore some functionality in ppt 2016, I decided to rewrite my code to limit the number of lines shown to prevent the 'resize' table call:

```
...
table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange = table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.lines(1,2)
table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange = table.Cell(2,2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.lines(1,1)
table.Cell(2, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange = table.Cell(2, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.lines(1,1)
```

In theory, you can use the .height; .Textrange; and the height of your font to figure the size of font you need inorder to 'shrink' the text to fit.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I asked this question a long time ago and can't even remember what program it was in reference to.  However, given you're a new user and gave a beautifully thorough answer, I'll accept it as the solution since I suspect it could solve the issue I had.  Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to happen when there is too much text to fit into a cell? There is no UI concept in PowerPoint to prevent row auto resizing based on cell overflow as there is nowhere for the additional text to go as demonstrated by typing in a cell within PowerPoint. Therefore there is no API to do the same. I would record the row before and after inserting the text and truncate word by word as you say until the row height returns to the original value.